# Optimize two sql sentences adding indices

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I'm optimizing my SQL Server database using SQL Server Management Studio Activity Monitor.

The two more expensive sql sentences are:

```
set @codesToPrintCount = 
    (select count(CodeId)
        from Code
        where CommissioningFlag = 255
        and AggregationLevelId = @codeLevel);

SET @code = (SELECT TOP 1 Serial
                FROM Code
                WHERE CommissioningFlag = 255
                    and AggregationLevelId = @codeLevel);
```

This is `Code` table sql script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Code] (
    [CodeId]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Serial]            NVARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [AggregationLevelId]  TINYINT      NOT NULL,
    [CommissioningFlag] TINYINT        NOT NULL,
    [ ... ]
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CODE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CodeId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UC_CODE_SERIAL] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Serial] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Code_AggregationLevelConfiguration]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationLevelId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[AggregationLevelConfiguration] ([AggregationLevelConfigurationId])
)
```

I don't know how I can speed up these sentences.

There are more rows in `Code` that table have the same value on `AggregationLevelId` column than columns with the value 255 on `CommissioningFlag`. In other words, on `Code` table there 1.050.000 rows with `AggregationLevelId` equals to `@codeLevel` and 32 rows or less with the value 255 in `CommissioningFlag` column.

Is it a good idea add two indices on this table? One for `CommissioningFlag` and another one for `AggregationLevelId`.

At this moment there are 1.100.000 rows on `Code` table and they get 23ms and 78ms respectably to execute.

By the way, these two sentences are in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not interested in rows that aren't 255, you could use a filtered index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix255 ON Code (AggregationLevelId)
INCLUDE (Serial, CodeId) 
WHERE CommissioningFlag = 255;
```

This means it will only index the ones that have 255, in AggregationLevelId order, including the values of Serial and CodeId because you need to count/return those.

If you cannot (or do not want to) use a filtered index, try the following (as originally suggested in a comment):

```
CREATE INDEX pick_a_name_for_the_index
ON Code (CommissioningFlag, AggregationLevelId) 
INCLUDE (Serial, CodeId);
```